# Python 3.4 - Requests - Login issue

Tags: python, forms, post, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to login into a website using post. I have this form...

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="login_form" class="formposition" style="display: block;">
<input type="text" name="btc_address" id="login_form_btc_address">
<input type="password" name="password" id="login_form_password">
<input type="submit" value="LOGIN!" id="login_button" class="button expand" style="margin:0;">
```

I wrote this code:

```
import requests
url = "https://freebitco.in/?op=home"
values = { "btc_address": "username", "password": "password"}
r = requests.post(url, data=values)
```

However, when I run the code it doesn't work... can someone give me an advice?

Comment: What happens, there is an error?

Comment: There is no error, simply it doesn't log in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using firebug in firefox, you can see that when you login into the website, posting password and address is not enough, you need:

```
'btc_address': 'your_btc_address',
'csrf_token': 'the_csrf_token',
'op': 'login',
'password': 'your_password'
```

Comment: Ok, I've done some researches and now my code is   
    url = "https://freebitco.in/?op=home"
    session = requests.Session()
    session.get(url)
    token = session.cookies['csrf_token']
    values = { 'btc_address': 'my_id',
           'csrf_token': token,
           'op': 'login',
           'password': 'my_password',
           }
    r = session.post(url, data=values)

when I run it and try to print r, it says "Response: 200" so the login should be successfully done, but if I try to look for a text that is present in the page, I can't find it... am I making another mistake?

Comment: @TestaDiRapa Sorry that I don't have a freebitco account, so I can't reproduce this problem and give you more advice. Wish you good luck.